# Override default application to handle intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a code for opening URL with browser:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
startActivity(i);
```

My question is, if user has set up default app for opening url, is there a way to override the default app and show application choose dialog instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i just found a solution. it was a so simple:

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, title));
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not know the exact answer to your question, but there is a bit more complicated decision. You can get a list of browsers, that installed on smartphone:

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(myIntent,PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

And then create a choose dialog manually.

P.S. Maybe there is a more simple solution ...

Comment: probably this will solve my problem. i set my app for handling soundcloud urls, but actually i have a case when need to open auth2/connect url in the browser and not in my app. actually what i needed was a way to exclude a `android:pathPrefix` or
`android:pathPattern` for that url, but there is no way to exclude. and by soundcloud's urls, there is no way to include all other prefixes/patterns.